# Adding OpenID to my website

Tags: openid

I want to add OpenID to my website. My question is: How can I get an ID or a unique identifier for the user that just logged in to my site? I want to use the ID to save user preferences in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the user's OpenID Identifier itself as the unique ID for the user.